# SQL 2008 All records in column in table updated to NULL

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-update

About 5 times a year one of our most critical tables has a specific column where all the values are replaced with NULL.  We have run log explorers against this and we cannot see any login/hostname populated with the update, we can just see that the records were changed.  We have searched all of our sprocs, functions, etc. for any update statement that touches this table on all databases on our server.  The table does have a foreign key constraint on this column.  It is an integer value that is established during an update, but the update is identity key specific.  There is also an index on this field. Any suggestions on what could be causing this outside of a t-sql update statement?

Comment: are you upgrading/migrating the DB's with some script?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by denying any client side dynamic SQL if at all possible. It is much easier to audit stored procedures to make sure they execute the correct sql including a proper where clause. Unless your sql server is terribly broken, they only way data is updated is because of the sql you are running against it.

All stored procs, scripts, etc. should be audited before being allowed to run.

If you don't have the mojo to enforce no dynamic client sql, add application logging that captures each client sql before it is executed. Personally, I would have the logging routine throw an exception (after logging it) when a where clause is missing, but at a minimum, you should be able to figure out where data gets blown out next time by reviewing the log. Make sure your log captures enough information that you can trace it back to the exact source. Assign a unique "name" to each possible dynamic sql statement executed, e.g., each assign a 3 char code to each program, and then number each possible call 1..nn in your program so you can tell which call blew up your data at "abc123" as well as the exact sql that was defective.

ADDED COMMENT

Thought of this later. You might be able to add / modify the update trigger on the sql table to look at the number of rows update prevent the update if the number of rows exceeds a threshhold that makes sense for your. So, did a little searching and found someone [wrote an article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1851/prevent-accidental-update-or-delete-commands-of-all-rows-in-a-sql-server-table/) on this already as in this snippet

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Purchasing].[uPreventWholeUpdate] 
ON [Purchasing].[VendorContact] 
FOR UPDATE AS 
BEGIN
     DECLARE @Count int
     SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT;

     IF @Count >= (SELECT SUM(row_count)
         FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats 
         WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Purchasing.VendorContact' ) 
         AND index_id = 1)
     BEGIN
         RAISERROR('Cannot update all rows',16,1) 
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
         RETURN;
     END
END
```

Though this is not really the right fix, if you log this appropriately, I bet you can figure out what tried to screw up your data and fix it.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Transaction log explorer should be able to see who executed command, when, and how specifically command looks like.

Which log explorer do you use? If you are using [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) you need to enable connection monitor feature in order to capture additional login details.

Answer (score 0):

This might be like using a sledgehammer to drive in a thumb tack, but have you considered using SQL Server Auditing (provided you are using SQL Server Enterprise 2008 or greater)?